# timestamp in firebase/firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

When I save timestamp dates on firestore, it saves as a timestamp datatype.
But when I retrieve the data into React, sometimes it is retrieved as a timestamp and I can convert it to JS date using `toDate()` but other times is retrieved as `{_seconds, _nanoseconds}` and I need to convert it manually.

It seems very confusing. Is there a best practise about how to save and how to retrieve dates from Google Firestore?
Thanks

Comment: What if you saved it as a string instead?

Comment: But is it the best practise? why do Firestore implements timestamps then>

Comment: Can you reliably write code that produces the seconds/nanoseconds variant? Or does it seem random?

Comment: I save it from React as `Date` type, and it automatically saves it to Firsetore as `timestamp` . But on retraival it seems random: sometimes it automatically converts it back to `Date`, but other times is retrieved as `{_seconds, _nanoseconds}` and I need to parse it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to store dates in Firestore is through the Timestamp, you could store them through Strings, but it would be a huge pain to convert it back to `Date` so there really isn't any other better way to do it, unfortunately.